# Identify this two mast one funnel side paddle-steamer boat circa 1900

Tags: naval, identification

[image]

I am trying to identify [this side paddle wheel steamer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4ukZ.jpg). Looks like a wedding party just forward of the sail. Can't ID the flag. Image/photo is gelatin silver so early 1900s most probably.

Comment: link the photo?

Comment: Perhaps you could reformulate your question as a request rather than a demand.

Comment: It looks to me like a [North River Steamboat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_River_Steamboat)

Comment: I think @CGCampbell is right. That flag on the back looks like it could be a US flag. The front flag I can't identify. It doesn't match any historical New York flag or any state flag I could find.

Comment: Thank you very much. I also thought it was U.S. but had no clue what it might be. I appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: With your hint of North River Steamer I gogled and fount this image of the Clermont - I think that is the ship http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_River_Steamboat

Comment: @CGCampbell - I think you nailed it.  [Here's a period postcard for comparison](http://www.kiac-usa.com/hudsonFulton2k.jpg), and it matches down to the flag that I still can't identify...

Comment: It's actually, believe it or not, the Hudson's Clermont Steamboat Flag. Several descriptions of the Clermont talk about it flying the US flag and Hudson's flag. I was having trouble finding it, then I found "Documents of the Assembly of the State of New York, Volume 31; Volume 133, Issue 31" ... It talks about the Hudson-Fulton Celebration flag, itself Orange, White and Blue, with a 'Half-Moon Ship' a representation of the Clermont itself. I'm trying to find another visual representation.

Comment: No, I think I'm wrong. I found two postcards showing the flag and that's not it.

Comment: Could [this be the flag?](http://www.crwflags.com/fotw/flags/us-ny_hf.html) :)

Comment: @CGCampbell - Think you got the flag too.  Nice one.

Answer (score 13):

I believe this is the "Clermont" replica, built for the 1909 celebration.

The original Clermont the first steamboat built by Robert Fulton, of the Hudson-Fulton Steamboat company, which ran in New York up the Hudson river. It was the first commercially successful steamboat operated on the Hudson, or North River.

The flag being flown from the leading mast appears to be the Hudson-Fulton flag, details of which can be seen on [this page](http://www.crwflags.com/fotw/flags/us-ny_hf.html).

[image]

The Clermont was a [North River steamboat.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_River_Steamboat)

Comment: I really appreciate all of your comments and expertise. I have another unknown 1900s photo of a ship I will try to post tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

I came across these photos of the Robert Fulton's original Clermont and it appears that the paddle wheel is located more amidships, than in the original posted photo. I’m not sure if that is just optics or if the model reproduction in 1909 was not completely accurate or if it is a different vessel all together.[image]

Comment: I think that's a camera angle issue. OP's photo shows the stern of the ship, and yoy can't see all the bow, giving the illusuion of being off center.